# Controller is not saving form values to the json server with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a service called `feedbackFactory` that is returning a resource. I then have a controller called `FeedbackController` that is supposed to take the form and save it to the JSON server. The issue I'm running into is that the form is saving to the JSON server, but none of the values are being passed. It looks like the only thing being passed are the field names I have listed under var `feedback` in a separate controller. I'm not sure what I've done wrong.

```
.service('feedbackFactory', ['$resource', 'baseURL', function ($resource,     baseURL) {
    this.getFeedback = function () {
        return $resource(baseURL + "feedback/:id", null, {'save': {method: 'POST'}});
    };
}]);


.controller('FeedbackController', ['$scope', 'feedbackFactory', function ($scope, feedbackFactory) {
    $scope.sendFeedback = function() {  
    if ($scope.feedback.agree && ($scope.feedback.mychannel === "")) {
        $scope.invalidChannelSelection = true;
    }
    else {
        $scope.invalidChannelSelection = false;
        $scope.feedback = {mychannel:"", firstName:"", lastName:"", agree:"", email:"", comments:""};
        $scope.feedbackForm.$setPristine();
    }

};
    feedbackFactory.getFeedback().save($scope.feedback);


    }])
```

Comment: Please don't use screenshots to show code - post your code instead (4 space indent)

Comment: Sorry, @ManfredRadlwimmer, I've updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

You don't call your service inside of the sendFeedback function.
try

```
$scope.sendFeedback = function() {  
   ...
   feedbackFactory.getFeedback().save($scope.feedback);
};
```

to save your data